# how to illustrate the improvement between two prediction modes statisticlly

Tags: dataset, statistics, compare

I have a problem on how to compare two data sets statistically, and am very appreciate your help.

Problem:
i have two data sets from two prediction mode, such as M1={1 2 3 4 5}, and M2={3 4 2 5 6}, which are the mean square error between raw and predicted data. how or what tools i could used to find and show the improvements from M2 to M1?

What i did:
i tried the standard deviations for each set, and compared them. there are some increasing but not that obvious. what other tests i can do on this issue and how to tell the improvement is significant or not?

thanks for you help.